# How to generate image thumbnails in PHP in 300X200 dimensions?

Tags: php, thumbnails, phpthumb

I'm using the below code to generate image thumbnails in PHP. It generates the thumbnails proportional to the image height and width dimensions.

```
make_thumb('images/image.jpg', 'images-generated-thumbs/7.jpg', 300, 200);

function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width, $desired_height) {

    /* read the source image */
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
    $desired_height = floor($height*($desired_width/$width));
    $desired_width  = floor($width*($desired_height/$height));

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
    imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
}
```

For the above example, it generates the `7.jpg` thumbnail with 299x187 in size. So, my question is how to fill the rest of the pixels ((300-299)x(300-187)) in white color.
If we remove the `$desired_height` variable in above code, it exactly generates a thumbnail with 300 in width, so only need is to fill the rest of the height with the white color.

Comment: Why do you need to have those thumbnails strictly in size 300*200?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you modify the width/height, store them:

```
$actual_width = $desired_width;
$actual_height = $desired_height;
$desired_height = floor($height*($desired_width/$width));
$desired_width  = floor($width*($desired_height/$height));
```

When you are doing the canvas:

```
/* create a new, "virtual" image */
$virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($actual_width, $actual_height);
```

Virtual image at this point is black, fill it with white:

```
$white = imagecolorallocate($virtual_image, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($virtual_image, 0, 0, $white );
```